# How to toggle two images when clicking on the parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to toggle two images by clicking on the parent a tag.

here is my JavaScript

```
$("#VerColMenu > li > a").click(function() {
    var src = ($(this).children()[0].attr('src') === 'img/plus.png')
    ? 'img/minus.png'
    : 'img/plus.png';
   $(this).children()[0].attr('src', src);
});
```

but nothing happens here.

Comment: Have you placed this script inside of a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: You could try with the calss name only instead of checking img src. Could you provide your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching `[0]` to a jQuery object retrieves the under-lying DOM object.  Along with the above/below answers, you can also use [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to get the first element in a jQuery array set:

```
$("#VerColMenu > li > a").click(function() {
    var src = ($(this).children().first().attr('src') === 'img/plus.png') ? 'img/minus.png' : 'img/plus.png';
    $(this).children().first().attr('src', src);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6jE8A/)

This of course does have to be wrapped in `$(document).ready()` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

`attr` is a jQuery method not a DOM method so you don't need `[0]`. Try this:

```
$('#VerColMenu a').click(function(){
  var $img = $(this).children();
  var src = $img.attr('src');
  $img.attr('src', src === 'img/plus.png' ? 'img/minus.png' : 'img/plus.png');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `.children()[0]`
gets the children as the DOM object and not a jQuery Object..

And .attr() can be used only on jQuery objects..

Try the **:eq** selector instead of  **.children()**

```
 $("#VerColMenu > li > a").click(function() {
      var src = ($(this).find('img:eq(0)').attr('src') === 'img/plus.png')
    ? 'img/minus.png'
    : 'img/plus.png';
   $(this).find('img:eq(0)') .attr('src', src);
});
```

I am assuming by `.children()[0]`  you meant the first image inside the li ,
so using `img:eq(0)`  which will select the first image element inside the li..

Answer (score 0):

use this code it can help u

```
 function toggle(a) {
        if (isloaded) {
            document.getElementById(a).src=toggleimage[i_image];
        }
        i_image++
        if (i_image>1) {i_image=0}
    }

 <a href="javascript:toggle()"><img name="togglepicture" src="p1.gif" border="0"></a>
```